# Get selected image path through Asset in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, imagepicker

I used [multi_image_picker:](https://pub.dev/packages/multi_image_picker/versions/4.7.15/license) to select images from the internal storage. This library returns `List`  of  `Asset`, but I want as an image path, I used `FlutterAbsolutePath`

```
var path = await FlutterAbsolutePath.getAbsolutePath(resultList[i].identifier);
```

but this is not supported to null safety, How can I get an image path using the similar library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FlutterAbsolutePath is not supported to null safety**

I used button click event to get the image Path from Asset

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),

        onPressed: () async {

              final key = DateTime.now().toString();
              File file = await getImageFileFromAssets(images[1]);

              for(int i=0;i<images.length;i++)
                {
                  print('# file path is ${file.path} #');
                }

        },
      ),
```

The method which is converting Asset to the image path

```
Future<File> getImageFileFromAssets(Asset asset) async {
    final byteData = await asset.getByteData();

    final tempFile =
    File("${(await getTemporaryDirectory()).path}/${asset.name}");
    final file = await tempFile.writeAsBytes(
      byteData.buffer
          .asUint8List(byteData.offsetInBytes, byteData.lengthInBytes),);

    return file;
  }
```